# How placeholders as _1 in a callback works?

Tags: c++

How the compiler interpret the symbol `_1`, and how the binding take place?
Consider the following example:

```
class A {
public:
    boost::function<void (int x)> g;
};

class B {
public:
    B() {}
    static void foo(int i) { cout << "Hack: " << i <<endl;  }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.g = boost::bind(B::foo,_1);
    a.g(2);
    return 0;
}
```

What magic happens internally in the line `boost::bind(B::foo,_1);`?

And how `_1` is maped to the argument passed in the next line `a.g(2);`?

> Output: 
> Hack: 2

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders for the standard documentation on them since they were added C++11. Basically they are just specific types and values that `bind` knows how to interpret.

Comment: The compiler interprets `_1` as a name, same as it would interpret `x`. The implementation of that name is in the boost library, which is open source so you can examine it yourself.

Comment: But can you explain the complete mechanism in which `_1` is mapped to the argument passed in `a.g(2);`

Comment: This is probably one of the most complex parts of the STL. I know that I can't explain it myself. (As in, not that you shouldn't seek an answer, but I'm not sure that anyone will be able to give an easy one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain to the best of my ability. First and foremost, `_1` is nothing but a global variable. There is nothing special about it in this regard, and it could be named anything else as well - `placeholder1`, or `SergeyA`. However, name like `_1` is short, has well-understood meaning, and begins with `_`, which reduces likelihood of it clashing with other global names in the program.

The magic is in the type of this variable. It has a special type, which is reflected in generated `bind*` object. Later, when `operator()` is called, the type is recognized to take an argument from `operator()` arguments.

Here is some illustrating C++-like pseudocode, which is not correct, but is illustrative:

```
template<class F, class... ARG>
struct bound {
    bound(F f, ARGS&&... args) : bound_args(args...), functor(f) { }
    std::tuple<ARG...> bound_args;
    template<class... T>  
    void operator()(T&&... args);

    F f;
};

template<class F, class... T>
auto bind(F f, T&& args) {
    return bound<std::remove_reference_t<T>...>(f, args...);
}
```

Now, let's introduce a placeholder type.

```
template<size_t N>
struct placeholder {
   enum { position = N; };
   template<class...T>
   auto operator()(T&&... args) {
         return std::get<position>(std::make_tuple(arg...));
   }
};

placeholder<0> _1;
placeholder<1> _2;
```

So far so good. Now, let's see how the operator() actually works on bound object:

```
template<class... BOUND_ARGS>
template<class... CALL_ARGS>
void bound_object<BOUND_ARGS...>::operator() (CALL_ARGS&&... args) {
     call_impl(args..., make_index_sequence<sizeof...(BOUND_ARGS)>{});
}
```

make_index_sequence here is needed to extract tuple values into function arguments, so do not pay too much attention to it. And here is call_impl;

```
template<class... BOUND_ARGS>
template<class... CALL_ARGS, size_t... ix>
void  bound_object<BOUND_ARGS...>::call_impl(CALL_ARGS&&... args, std::index_sequence<ix...>) {
   f(to_arg().(std::get<ix>(bound_args), args...)...);
}
```

And the last piece of puzzle is `to_arg`:

```
template<class B, class... ARGS>
auto to_arg(B&& b, ARGS... args) {
    return b;
}

template<class... ARGS>
auto to_arg(placeholder<0> p, ARGS&&... args) {
     return p(args);
}

template<class... ARGS>
auto to_arg(placeholder<1> p, ARGS&&... args) {
     return p(args);
}
```

The whole of `to_arg` here is to give you either the bound argument or one of the supplied arguments, based on the bound argument type. In my example above, I used 3 overloads since you can partially specialize a function, but of course, it would make more sense to put it in a class and partially specialize the class.

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot! Now I need to read about **Reflection**, **tuples** and `make_index_sequence`

Comment: Reflection is not relevant here, but tuples are.